# Cannot implicitly convert type 'DbSet<Logs>' to 'Logs'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I'm having issues with the following module in my dbcontext api method page, should I be trying to convert my Logs to Logs?

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Http; 
using System.Web.Http; 

namespace Logging.Models 
{
    public class Log : DbContext    
    {
        public Log() : base("name=LogContext")      
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Log>(null);
         }

        public DbSet<Logs> Logs { get; set; }

        public Logs GetLog(int Id)      
        {           
            return Logs.Find(Id);       
        }

        public Logs AddLog(Logs p)      
        { 
            Logs.Add(p);
            SaveChanges();
            return p;       
        }       

        public Logs GetLogsByName(string lookupname) 
        {
            List<Logs> mylist = new List<Logs>(); 
            mylist = mylist.Where(p =>
                p.LoggerName.Contains(lookupname)).ToList();            

            foreach (var item in mylist) 
            {
                Logs.Add(item);
            }

            return Logs; <-- error come here see subject line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't adding anything to `mylist`.  And change the name of your context from `Log` to `LogContext`.  "Log" has a very different meaning, making your class name misleading.  Lastly, what line is giving you the error?

Comment: What a way to get help. You should just post the code that is relevant to solving the problem. Placing your code base and expecting people to guess isn't going to get you help. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips

Comment: As Camilo notes, your naming conventions aren't helping - you have a class `Logs` which is also the name of the `DbSet` parameter, and then the context is just `Log`. The line you've highlighted, you're attempting to return the parameter `Logs` as a DbSet<Logs> rather than an item of the class `Logs`

Comment: The line `List<Logs> mylist = new List<Logs>();` doesn't do what you think it does - you're creating an empty list of type `Logs` and then attempting to query it, rather than querying the DbSet<Logs> on the context - the `Logs` property is already usable as `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`

Comment: I read your code, and it doesn't do what you think it does. `public Logs GetLogsByName(string lookupname)` is saying "this method will return one object of type `Logs`". Then you create an empty list of type `Logs` and try to find something in it, if you do find something in it, you then add that to the collection (DbSet) `Logs` (although it is probably already in there). You then attempt to return the collection to the caller, even though the caller is only expecting a single object - hence the compiler saying it can't cast 'DbSet<Logs>' to 'Logs'

Comment: Oh goodness, please fix how you are naming things in your code. Why are you intentionally doing this? `public Logs AddLog(Logs p)` where Logs is a DbSet???

Comment: Did you fix it yet? People have been telling you the solution, but I see you haven't marked an answer. Your naming style has confused even you it seems.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My controller:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("GetByName")]
    public IEnumerable<Logs> GetByName(string loggername)
    {
        var log = _repository.GetLogsByName(loggername);
        if (log == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(
                Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        else
        {
            return log;
        }
    }
```

My dbcontext whatever:

```
        public IEnumerable<Logs> GetLogsByName(string lookupname)
    {
        List<Logs> mylist = Logs.ToList<Logs>();
        return  mylist.Where(p => p.LoggerName.Contains(lookupname)).ToList();

    }
```

Comment: How is that not the same as what Zhaph - Ben Duguid suggested in his comment to your question? Your code: `List<Logs> mylist = new List<Logs>();` was assigning myList to a new list and you were trying to query that. You were told to query the `Logs` property. The answer by Camilo Terevinto does essentially the same thing.

Comment: Well good on you then. Your "proper answer" is exactly the same as this `return this.Logs.Where(p => p.LoggerName.Contains(lookupname)).ToList();` by Camilo. If you use the refactoring tools, C# will offer to inline your temporary variable and produce this code. You were given the answer a long time ago.

Comment: @Fabulous thanks for defending my answer, and this is still wrong (the OP will never get a single value)

Comment: Your "dbcontext whatever" will have some performance issues if you end up with a lot of records in the Logs table - by calling `Logs.ToList<Logs>()` you're telling the framework to fetch all the records from the storage, and then query them in memory - it's usually more efficient to use the `.Where(...)` call on Logs directly as then the query is sent to the database and it only returns the matching results.

Comment: It's a testament to how awesome SO is that people are still trying to help Lyle.  I love you guys, and I love SO.

Answer (score 4):

This is how your method should look like so that the search is done in the database (rather than in-memory) and the method returns the list of logs that match the filter:

```
public List<Logs> GetLogsByName(string lookupname) 
{
    return this.Logs.Where(p => p.LoggerName.Contains(lookupname)).ToList();   
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148931/discussion-on-answer-by-camilo-terevinto-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-dbsetl).

Answer (score 3):

`Logs` is a property of type `DbSet<Logs>` where `Logs` is also a type. This is probably the confusion. Your return statement isn't returning `Logs` the type but rather `Logs` the property (which is of type `DbSet<Logs>`). Your confusion could be cleared up with better naming.

`DbSet<Logs>` can be cast to `IEnumerable<Logs>` or `IQueryable<Logs>` but your usage makes it look like the type `Logs` is already a collection of some type (you aren't showing the `Logs` class to be sure) which means you're returning a collection of collections which can't be cast to a simple collection.

Comment: If you can't change the names, consider using the full namespace for the `Logs` property and type so it's clear what you're intending.

Comment: I believe you are too optimistic thinking that `Logs` is anything but a single `Log` with a bad name

Comment: I'm not renaming anything sorry I'm just down to one line that needs converting

Comment: dear people my whole api works fine, I'm just adding one thing a query for loggername

Comment: @Lyle Then don't rename - add the full namespace so the compilers knows what you're doing. Right now you're returning DbSet<Logging.Models.Logs> but your method is decorated as returning Logging.Models.Logs. You're returning a collection of Logs when you want to return a single Logs. Throw a .First() on your return statement or something and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: You don't HAVE a conversion issue. You can't cast Logs[] to Logs. Does that make it more clear? Your method signature says you are returning a single Logs object but what's next to your `return` statement is a collection / array / enumerable / whatever name you like - of Logs. Your method wants 1, you're trying to return many.

Comment: I don't know because I don't know what you /intend/ to do here. Do you want to return the full collection / enumerable / array of Logs or a single Logs? Change either your method signature `public IEnumberable<Logs> GetLogsByName(string lookupname)` OR change your return `return Logs.First(...);`

Comment: @Lyle Your question has been answered and clarified a half dozen times. Your answer is there. Short of posting your code on GitHub and someone physically making the changes for you I'm not sure what else you expect here. You have everything you need to fix your code.

Comment: @Lyle I'm sorry if you're having trouble understanding what's being said. While a naming change would help you see the problem better, my answer tells you exactly what's happening and what you need to do to resolve it. I suggested you add the full namespace to your objects so you can see what's happening but you seem to be making 0 effort. If you already knew what you needed to do, why ask a question? And if you asked a question, why would you not try the one thing everyone is telling you?